# Examples of self-explainable models used in NLP other than prototype-based

Tags: natural-language-processing, explainable-ai

I am looking for all the methods used in NLP that are self-explainable, or explainable by design. That is to say, the ones that use the predictive model itself to explain the entire model's predictive reasoning (a.k.a. directly interpretable model).

I have only a few example in mind:

- *prototype-based methods*, models that reveal the network's reasoning by providing prototypical explanations. It may allow users to directly manipulate a network component according to their preferences like Rasa or, more recently, [Proto-Trex](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/355092869_Interactively_Generating_Explanations_for_Transformer-based_Language_Models).
- *Human-in-the-loop ML*, where the co-creation allows to interpret and update the model logic directly by enabling interaction with rule generators themselves. But as the first of these are created with deep learning, is it truly part of explainable AI? An example of this is [HEIDL](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.11184.pdf), which did reference to related work such as [Chorus](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/hci/pubs/pdfs/chorus.pdf)